# How to delete last character in text widget tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget, python-3.6

I am attempting to make the following code work:
It is meant to delete the last character of the text widget named _textBox (as a backspace on a keyboard would usually do)...

```
def addChar(_textBox, char):
    global charCount
    if charCount <= 15:
        if char == "backSpace":
            _textBox.delete(charCount, END)
            if charCount != 0:
                charCount = charCount - 1
        else:
            _textBox.insert(END, char)
            charCount = charCount + 1
    print(charCount)
```

It seems the only problem is the '.delete()' part of the code...

Does anybody know how i can use this properly to remove **only the last** character in the text widget?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please reread and then create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @PatrickArtner  I do realise that it may not be very pythonic code... however the main problem I am facing is the '.delete()' part of the code... other than that, the rest of the program works like a breeze

Comment: What is requested has nothing to do with it being pythonic or not.

Comment: MVCE is about us being able to copy your code into our IDE and replicating the error. Your code uses TK and Textboxes, somehow you get the addChar - Method called wich takes 2 parameters of which  1 seems to be a tkinter-TextBox() the other a String called char that might hold backspace .. all in all there is so much code missing that we can not replicate your problem whithout spending 2h on recreating what we _think_ you do - and we will get it wrong in at least 3 places. But good that you solved it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Good Guys!

I've followed Pat's Advice in rewriting the portion of code and it now works brilliantly!
Here it is if anyone wants it:

```
def addChar(_textBox, char):
    global charCount, strToInsert
    if charCount == 0:
        strToInsert = ""
    if char == "backSpace":
        strToInsert = strToInsert[:-1]
        if charCount != 0:
            charCount = charCount - 1
    else:
        if charCount <= 15:
            strToInsert = strToInsert + char
            charCount = charCount + 1

    _textBox.delete("1.0", END)
    _textBox.insert(END, strToInsert)
```

**FYI:** I do set the variable charCoun in another function...

Answer (score 5):

To delete a character, you must give the index immediately before the character you want to delete (ie: to delete the very first character you would give it `"1.0"`).

The index `END` represents the position just after invisible newline automatically added by tkinter. "end-1" represents the position immediately before this newline.  Since you want to delete the last character that the user entered (which is before this newline), you must use `"end-2c"` (end minus two characters).

Answer (score 3):

To delete only the last character in an entry widget
You can use the following code

```
entryname.delete(len(entryname.get())-1,END)
```

Answer (score 0):

I build a simple project here:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
screen=Tk()
screen.title("Test")
def reponsive():
   txt.grid()
def ins(text):
   txt.delete('1.0', END)
   txt.insert(INSERT,text)
   txt.grid()
def delete():
   text=txt.get("1.0",END)
   text=text[:-2]
   ins(text)
bt=Button(screen,command=delete,text="DEL").grid()
txt=Text(screen)
reponsive()
screen.mainloop()
```