# How to delete first character of tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I am struggling with `tkinter`. I simply want to delete the first character of a text widget, for example on button click. I have seen [Bryan Oakleys answer here][1] but unfortunately it does not work for me.
Like he said I tried it like this:

`text.delete("1.0")`

But like I said it does not work. I also do not get any error. It simply does not work.

```
from tkinter import *
import time


class TipManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        self.root.bind("<KeyPress>", self.click)
        self.clicks = 0
        self.chars = []
        self.cps = 0
        self.start = time.time()
        self.average()
        self.text = Text(self.root,tabs=2,font=("Arial", 30))
        self.text.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.root.mainloop()




    def click(self,e):
        if e.char.isalpha() or e.char == " ":
            self.chars.append(e.char)
            self.clicks += 1
            if len(self.chars) > 15:
                self.text.delete("1.0")
            self.text.configure(state="normal")
            self.text.insert(END, e.char)
            self.text.configure(state="disabled")


        if e.char == "\x7f":
            if not len(self.chars) == 0:
                self.text.configure(state="normal")
                self.text.delete("end-2c")
                self.text.configure(state="disabled")
                del self.chars[-1]

    def average(self):
        self.cps = self.clicks
        print(f"Your average typing speed was {self.cps} c/s")
        self.clicks = 0
        self.root.after(1000, self.average)




tipp_10 = TipManager()
```

This is my full code
[1]: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49232866/how-to-delete-last-character-in-text-widget-tkinter#:~:text=The%20index%20END%20represents%20the,(end%20minus%20two%20characters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49232866/how-to-delete-last-character-in-text-widget-tkinter#:%7E:text=The%20index%20END%20represents%20the,(end%20minus%20two%20characters)).

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Please post a [mre]. We prefer something we can copy and paste then run.

Comment: @TheLizzard yes I tried but does not work either

Comment: @PucciLaCanton The problem is that the `tkinter.Text` is `"disabled"` when you are trying to delete the character. Move the `self.text.configure(state="normal")` before the `for` loop.

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: @BryanOakley I don't think there is an error. It just doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```py
if len(self.chars) > 15:
    self.text.delete("1.0")
self.text.configure(state="normal")
self.text.insert(END, e.char)
self.text.configure(state="disabled")
```

to:

```py
self.text.configure(state="normal")
if len(self.chars) > 15:
    self.text.delete("1.0")
self.text.insert(END, e.char)
self.text.configure(state="disabled")
```

The `<tkinter.Text>`'s state must be `"normal"` when you `.insert`/`.delete` from it.

Comment: Wow what a dumb error from my side. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your text box is enabled before you insert/delete from it. So put `self.text.configure(state="normal")` before this line:

```
if len(self.chars) > 15:
self.text.delete("1.0")
```

Comment: No unfortunately not

Comment: Next time please try to find the root cause of the problem described in the question.